# SparkException: Job 2 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down, Spark Yarn handling large dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I run hail0.1 on a Spark cluster via Google Dataproc.

I successfully ran 1 Tb dataset, import vcf and write to vds.
when I try to ran 3 Tb dataset, use the same code, it report: `SparkException: Job 2 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down` I guess it is OOM exception, thus I upgrade drive.mem and executor.mem, still report same error but it do finished more task. (first time aborted at around 10000/600000, 2nd time aborted at 30000/60000)

What could be some troubleshooting steps here? my driver and executor mem already be high, I think.

1st time cluster configuration:

```
Master node
Standard (1 master, N workers)
Machine type
n1-highmem-32
Number of GPUs
0
Primary disk type
pd-standard
Primary disk size
200GB
Local SSDs
0
Worker nodes
4
Machine type
n1-highmem-16
Number of GPUs
0
Primary disk type
pd-standard
Primary disk size
100GB
Local SSDs
1
Secondary worker nodes
10
Machine type
n1-highmem-16
Number of GPUs
0
Primary disk type
pd-standard
Primary disk size
100GB
Local SSDs
0
Preemptible
true
Properties
distcp:mapreduce.map.java.opts
-Xmx1664m
distcp:mapreduce.map.memory.mb
2048
distcp:mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
-Xmx1664m
distcp:mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
2048
hdfs:dfs.namenode.handler.count
80
hdfs:dfs.namenode.service.handler.count
40
hdfs:dfs.replication
1
mapred-env:HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE
4000
mapred:mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores
1
mapred:mapreduce.map.java.opts
-Xmx3276m
mapred:mapreduce.map.memory.mb
4096
mapred:mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores
2
mapred:mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
-Xmx8192m
mapred:mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
10240
mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts
-Xmx8192m
mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores
2
mapred:yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb
10240
spark-env:SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY
4000m
spark:spark.driver.extraJavaOptions
-Xss4M
spark:spark.driver.maxResultSize
60g
spark:spark.driver.memory
200g
spark:spark.executor.cores
8
spark:spark.executor.extraJavaOptions
-Xss4M
spark:spark.executor.memory
37237m
spark:spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max
1g
spark:spark.task.maxFailures
20
spark:spark.yarn.am.memory
37237m
spark:spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead
3723
spark:spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead
3723
yarn-env:YARN_NODEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE
4000
yarn-env:YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE
4000
yarn-env:YARN_TIMELINESERVER_HEAPSIZE
4000
yarn:yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
81920
yarn:yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
81920
yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
2048
```

2nd time I upgrade master node to n1-highmem-96, work node to n1-highmem-32, spark.driver.memory 600g, spark.driver.maxResultSize 180g, other set were automatically adjusted by Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

The needs of your job depend on what the job does, such as whether it does repartitioning, grouping or reducing by key, etc.

In a scalably configured job, the master that runs the driver program ideally should not need a lot of memory. A few common pitfalls sometimes leads to heavy space usage on a master node:

1. Accidentally explicitly setting `.setMaster("local[*]")` in your Spark code, possibly a holdover from local testing purposes -- this would tell Spark to run in single-node mode even if a full distributed cluster is available
2. Calling "collect()" on a huge distributed dataset
3. Doing explicit processing logic in the main program outside of any distributed dataframe or RDD operations.

You should make sure your workers are actually getting any work assigned to them instead of just bottlenecking in your master node for one of the reasons listed above.

If your workers are indeed doing work, it might not be a master-node OOM causing the issue. Looking at your configuration, your disks seem extremely small for the dataset size. If a job is definitely "map-only", this is sometimes okay, but in almost all cases you're better off from a cost perspective by adding larger disks to all your nodes, because [Google Compute Engine disk performance scales up with its size](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance). And since even 2000GB of pd-standard only costs as much hourly as about 2 CPUs, if you're running very large machines like 96-core highmem instances, removing any disk-performance bottleneck is almost certainly going to save you both time and money in the long term (e.g. going from 100GB to 2000GB improves performance by even 2 percent on a 96-core machine, the extra disk cost as more than paid for itself).

If there is *any* repartitioning, grouping, etc., happening, then your workers will rely on local disk for scratch/shuffle space. In this case, if your total disk space is smaller than the necessary working set of shuffle data, your job will not succeed. Overall, bumping up disk space to 2000GB on all nodes might be the solution.